# Why does Apache treat some files differently with regards to caching?

Tags: ajax, apache, caching

Base problem: I'm working on a web-app that pulls in an XML file via Ajax. Initially my issue was the file seeming to indefinitely cache in the browser and never issue an HTTP request at all. This is easily mitigated by adding the 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' request header. However, now I'm on the other side of the spectrum with the server always returning 200 along with the file contents and never a 304.

Debugging this with Fiddler has left me even more perplexed. Eventually I selected a request in Fiddler for a PNG file that was returning 304. I duplicated the request and then changed only the URL to point to the XML file instead. The XML file still however returns 200 despite having identical request headers as that of the 304 returning PNG file. Apache also returns many additional response headers for the XML file. The PNG file only returns Date, ETag, Server, Connection, and Keep-Alive. The XML file has all of these as well as Vary, Content-Length, Last-Modified, Accept-Ranges and Server.

I just want the XML file to be cached like any other file. If it's new on the server, return new content, otherwise respond with 304. So my question is, what settings are causing Apache to treat the XML file differently than the PNG file? Thanks.

EDIT - Per Covener's questions

1. No I didn't switch out the eTag, I can try doing that when I get
   back in the office.
2. Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
3. No idea, I'm running a default install of Uniform server with Apache for local development with no modifications. (Content-length is probably absent since the server is returning 304 with no content.)

EDIT-2
I noticed that Apache doesn't GZip the PNG file (appears according to Fiddler that it would actually be larger, so makes sense). If I remove Accept-Encoding from the request as well as the '-gzip' from the etag, Apache will return 304 for the XML file. The GZip compression is 10 to 1 for this file, so ideally, it would be nice to have the compression but still send 304's when appropriate.

Comment: When you replayed your conditional request, did you pick an appropriate ETAG for the XML file?

What's in the vary response header?

Why does your PNG not get served with Content-Length and Last-Modified?

Comment: @covener Answered in question.

Comment: Tried out the above experiment again, this time swapping out the eTag. Didn't help.